# 3D visualisation alternative plugins in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, 3d, qgis-3, qgis2threejs

As the qgis2threejs plugin is not available in QGIS3, what are the 3D visualisation alternatives to plugin Qgis2threejs in QGIS 3.0?

Comment: QGIS3 comes with its own, check the changelog.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx qgis2threejs creates a browser-based 3D view, the QGIS 3 3D view is internal. What does the asker want? We don't know.

Comment: The asker wants to know if there are alternative ways to create browser based 3D scenes from QGIS 3.0, since Qgis2threejs is not (or not yet?) available in QGIS 3.0. What's unclear with that? I recommend getting in touch with the author, and ask if and when porting to QGIS 3.0 is planned.

Comment: A look at https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs/blob/master/metadata.txt indicates that the author is working on porting it to QGIS 3.0 as well!

Answer (score 1):

I know that Qgis 3.0 has 3D support as a native feature now.... so you wouldn't need any plug-in...

http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.0.0/#category-51

Comment: thanks! i used the 3d View. I found the plugin qgis2threejs a better option even though its a web browser because there are a bunch of settings available with it which is missing in the internal built in 3d viewer.